# Why can't I change a global variable from inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
def displayInventory ():
    print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory))

def enterEcdysis():
    global xcash
    xcash -= 1
    displayInventory()

xcash = 3
inventory = [str(xcash) + ' Cash',] 
enterEcdysis()
```

I'm trying to make this print `['2 Cash,']`, but when I run it it still comes out as `3`. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here. Shouldn't `xcash -= 1` take one away from the global variable?

Answer (score 3):

It *is* updating `xcash`. The problem is `inventory` is out of date. You're setting it to `['3 Cash']` before the call to `enterEcdysis()` and you don't update it after `xcash` is modified.

Change your print statement to print `xcash` directly and you'll see it's working fine:

```
def displayInventory ():
    print ("Inventory: {} Cash".format(xcash))
```

Comment: further comment: the line "inventory = [str(xcash) + ' Cash',]" happens only once. It's not going to automatically change the contents of "inventory" whenever "xcash" changes. If you want "inventory" to change, you will need to call code to update it.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcash = 3
inventory = [str(xcash) + ' Cash',] 
enterEcdysis()
```

Consider the lines of code above.
You've created and set the variable *inventory* using the current value of *xcash* which is 3 before you call **enterEcdysis**.
Within **enterEcdysis**, you've subtracted 1 from the value of *xcash* but the variable *inventory* remains unchanged.
Thus, when you, later on, display the value of the variable *inventory*, you're still shown the value of *inventory* when it was defined (when *xcash* still equalled 3.)

```
def displayInventory ():
    print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory) + "\t" + str(xcash))
```

If you modify **displayInventory** as above, you'll see that the value of *xcash* was indeed changed but you've not changed the value of *inventory*.